# JSF application using IE11 with Enterprise Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, richfaces, internet-explorer-11, jsf-1.2, netweaver

Our application cannot run with `IE11` and `EM`. We are using modify **JSF-1.2** and **RichFaces 3.X** . When we run Web page on **IE11 without EM all working OK**, but we have to use `IE11` with `EM`.  Is any possible method to **disable EM for page from code**?

`IE` console raising error: "*XML5632: Only one root element is allowed.*" It occurs when moving between pages.

PS: Application working on `IE8`, `IE9` and `IE11` without any problems but when you try it with `IE11` and `EM` It´s raising error.

Comment: It is reasonable to _upgrade_ **JSF** and **RichFaces**? Or reprograme application with different technologies?

Comment: Enterprise mode definition: The page is currently being rendered in Enterprise Mode, which is an emulation of Windows Internet Explorer 8. And IE8 don't support iframe with <html> element. ( http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn640687.aspx ) No sense build application now to run on IE8 engine.

Comment: Try add http header "X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge" from Servlet filter. e.g: response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge");

Comment: Problem was with parsing xhtml..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for this problem is not sanding `XHTML` from server but native `HTML`. This providing filter which change response from `application/xhtml+xml` to `text/html`. Filter get response form header of user agent and find if is set `„compatible; msie 8.0“` which means, that `IE11` runs under Enterprise Mode and Emulate `IE8`.

Our implemented solution:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

   String userAgent = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("user-agent");

   if (userAgent != null && userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("compatible; msie 8.0"))
    {   
     chain.doFilter(request, new ForcableContentTypeWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response));
    }
    else 
    {
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

private class ForcableContentTypeWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
     public ForcableContentTypeWrapper(HttpServletResponse response)
    {
    super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentType(String type)
    {
      if (type.contains("application/xhtml+xml")) 
    {
        super.setContentType(type.replace("application/xhtml+xml", 
                                          "text/html"));
    }
    else 
    {
      super.setContentType(type);
    }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your application is just limited within the intranet and accessible within a confined network then you can disable EM thru the network's group policy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640688.aspx

or, you can try to remove your application's URL from the SiteList file (the file where the registry EM entry is pointing at mentioned in the link above) so your application will not be included in the EM site list

Additional references:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx

Comment: This is not solution for me.. our customer have company policy for this and application running in Frame under other application which have to be run on EM. I Am asking for disable EM for page from code..